# how i can make vim Auto-Indent like TextMate

Tags: vim, textmate

I am using the gVim7.3 on Windows 7

how i can make vim Auto-Indent like TextMate Especially when i used [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)

Sorry for my bad English
Because it is not my native language

Comment: Does your vim already autoindent and you are not happy with the result? Or doesn't it autoindent at all?

Comment: @evnu yes vim have autoindent ,, Is there a way to make it like autoindent in TextMate

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want and another of what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about TextMate or snipMate, but here is how we do it in VIM:

In your `.vimrc` file, have the following lines:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unpacked  snipMate into your $HOME\vimfiles.  If you not sure where is your $HOME, read pls [the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file). You can enter into vim these commands for help:

```
:version
:echo expand('~')
:echo $HOME
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

After unpacking you probably forgot edit your vimrc file. You **must** enter the

```
:filetype plugin on
```

command into your vimrc and restart your vim.